# Powershell (windows 11) move files and rename

Tags: command-line, powershell, batch-file, batch-rename

I am trying to write PowerShell that will allow me to clean up files and place them into folders and rename them to include a date in the filename, and once I work out the commands, I will script it.

However when trying with the following, I get error about cannot bind argument.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I am new to Powershell. I had managed to use in another script to do renaming (adding a filename prefix) to work using the get-childitem ...  | Rename-Item -NewName....  command.

```
PS T:\Incoming Students\Spring 2024\OTEAS\CF_DATAFILES> $date = '20231114'
PS T:\Incoming Students\Spring 2024\OTEAS\CF_DATAFILES>  get-childitem .\OTE_OTEAS_BARMAP_CHECKSCORE* | Move-Item $_.Name -Destination .\BM_Math_Test_Record_QA\+{$_.Name -replace '.csv', '_'+$date+'.csv'}
Move-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:1 char:59
+ ... -childitem .\OTE_OTEAS_BARMAP_CHECKSCORE* | Move-Item $_.Name -Destin ...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Move-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

Based on feedback below, I have modified the command to the following:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem BM_Math_Test_Record_QA_* ) {Move-Item -Path $file -Destination ($file.Directory.ToString()+"\BM_Math_Test_Record_QA\"+$file.BaseName.tostring()+"_"+$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd)+$file.Extension) -Verbose}
```

and it appears to be working (for now...)

Comment: You should use PowerShell ISE to step through line by line to very the exact line which is not evaluating to the value you are expecting. **It is also impossible to troubleshoot a script we don't have.** We need a MRE.

Comment: @Ramhound - (1) what is an MRE?  Also the entire script was those two lines.

Comment: So put them in a code block.  MRE stands for Minimal Reproduceable Example. This still could have been debugged using PowerShell ISE.

Comment: There is no explicit script; instead, the "commands" executed are embedded within the code block itself. This becomes evident upon scrolling over and observing the executed commands. Given the absence of an edit history (other than what I made to make this more clear wording wise), I find it puzzling to discern the specific scrutiny in this case. The code block visibly illustrates the execution of a set of commands, resulting in the reported error. In my view, the provided information already constitutes a sufficient Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE).

Comment: @psycoperl If you look over https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-7.3 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.3, and then search for "**Accept pipeline input**" you will see differences in this functionality between the two commands and the applicable parameters you are using. This should help you troubleshoot for a better starting point to work it out on your own but look over those and test single command examples first before looping, etc.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle - I missed the code because the error and the code were contained in the same quote block.

Comment: The misleading comment has the potential to shape a biased perspective on this issue, prompting individuals to vote for closure or take other actions based on your reputation. Given the substantial influence that higher-reputation users wield over those who make decisions based on such content in mind, I suggest addressing the misleading comment & reassessing the closure vote if it was indeed you too e.g. removal, reversal, etc. where ever/if applicable. I will destroy these comments soon since you have replied should corrective action be taken. Thank you & have a wonderful day/night!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I ended up changing the command to make it work:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem BM_Math_Test_Record_QA_* ) 
{Move-Item -Path $file -Destination ($file.Directory.ToString()+"\BM_Math_Test_Record_QA\"+$file.BaseName.tostring()+"_"+$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd)+$file.Extension) -Verbose}
```

Comment: With just a little trying some things, it is usually as easy as that! Good job!

Answer (score 3):

`$_` doesn't work in bare commands – it is only defined inside loops such as `ForEach-Object`. Some cmdlets directly take a list of objects as input without doing anything special, but once you want to do something custom with the objects you need a "foreach" loop:

```
get-childitem foo | foreach-object { do-something-with $_ }
 -or-
get-childitem foo | % { do-something-with $_ }
```

C#-style `foreach ($x in ...)` loops are also available.

Note that the `{ … }` wrap the entire 'Move' command, *not* just the part where you use $_.

For string concatenation inline, you'll probably want either

```
".\BM_Math\" + ($_.Name -replace ...)
 -or-
".\BM_Math\$($_.Name -replace ...)"
 -or-
".\BM_Math\$newname"
```

(the latter two probably don't require the quotes)

Comment: I apologize I'm lost: I tried Get-ChildItem OTE_OTEAS_BARMAP_CHECKSCORE* | Foreach-object {Move-Item -Path {$($_.BaseName).$($_extension)} -Destination {'.\BM_Math_Test_Record_QA_\'+$($_.BaseName)+'_'+$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd).$($_.extension)}}
Move-Item : Cannot evaluate parameter 'Path' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input. A script block cannot be evaluated without input.
At line:1 char:78
+ ... reach-object {Move-Item -Path {$($_.BaseName).$($_extension)} -Destin ...
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...

Comment: @psycoperl - If you have more information to share you should [edit] your question to include it.